# Get youtube channel videos of particular channel using PHP Code

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I want to display youtube videos for particular channel in XML format.
This is the channel for which I want to retrieve videos:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxiaIKXjo25U1AMCBAcplRQ
```

can anyone suggest how can i get XML format video listing for particular channel from youtube. 
**I just want URL for which i can get what i want**.
I can write PHP code to use XML retrieved from youtube API URL.

Comment: I've asked `Google` if it knows something about `youtube get data of a specific channel` and the first link was https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the URL for API that you need to use for your purpose. hope it helps.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCxiaIKXjo25U1AMCBAcplRQ/uploads?max-results=2
```

Comment: Youtube Api v3 not allowed this.here is some questions related to new api.
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube+data+api+v3